# How to prove $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(e)$ are not the same field?

Tags: extension-field, pi, transcendental-numbers

I know that it hasn't been shown that $\pi$ and $e$ are algebraically independent over $\mathbb{Q}$. However it must be easier to show that the fields $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(e)$ are not the same. Yet, I have no ideas on how to approach this problem. Does anyone can show a proof or give any useful hint?

Comment: As far as I know, it is unknown whether $\large \frac{\pi}{e}$ is rational. Doesn't that mean that we do not know whether the fields are equal ?

Comment: Presumably you mean whether they are the same subset of $\Bbb{R}$ :-)

Comment: They'll be the same field iff $e=(a\pi+b)/(c\pi+d)$ for some rational $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$. Good luck proving that ain't so!

Comment: It is a consequence of $e,\pi$ being transcendental numbers that $\mathbb{Q}(e)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$ are isomorphic as fields, so "the same field" in that more abstract sense.  Hence @Jyrki's comment is pertinent.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is an open problem. For all we know, it is *possible* that $e+\pi$ is a rational in which case the fields would clearly be the same.